# com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException in React native 67 version, Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra 5G

Tags: react-native

[image]

I don't know why this error in api lavel 12. in some divices please help.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS error doesn't have much info, You reported it from Crashlytics I presume

You can try to symbolicate your stacktrace to have more detail on the crash and find the right place in the code

https://reactnative.dev/docs/symbolication